# VBA Excle run a Powerpoint marco that takes in the excel filename

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, office-2016

I have this macro in an automatically created data file (part of the creation is inserting and running the macro).
I want to open a template file  and then need to run a PPT macro that takes in the excel data file name.  The one that called the macro (data1.xlsm)
I have this but can't figure out the macro call with the file name.

```
Dim PPTObj As Object 
Set PPTObj =    CreateObject("PowerPoint.application") 
With PPTObj 
.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Presentations\Company\Template.pptm" 
.Run  "Template.pptm!MainMacro" 
End With
```

.Run "Template.xlsm!MainMacro(filename)"  is what I am looking for.

Maybe the other direction is to get the object in PPT.
But how do I get the data file name/path without knowing it beforehand?

```
Set wb - getobject(openwexcelfile)
```

Since another program (not office) is creating the data file, I do not know it's name or directory, but it is the file calling the powerpoint macro and it will be open.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Just pass a parameter.  The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744221.aspx) on Application.Run shows pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I couldn't find out how to pass that parameter.  I was trying to do it inside the quotes.   .Run  "Template.pptm!MainMacro" ,filename,filepath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Comintern for the insight.
Here is the final solution.
The sleep is to allow PPT App to open before trying to run the macro.

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub auto_open()

fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim PPTObj As Object
Set PPTObj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
PPTObj.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\presentation\Template.pptm"
    Sleep (3000)
PPTObj.Run "Template.pptm!Main", fname, Path
End Sub
```